# Missing lib for Youtube Data API v3 Upload Video Sample

Tags: youtube-api

I tryed to upload a Video to Youtube with a simple Eclipse project, what i did wrong or wher are that libs?

Last but one line give me the type com.google.gdata.data.iEntry cannot be resolved.It is indirectly referenced from required .class file.

Last line give me the type com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException cannot be resolved.It is indirectly referenced from required .class file.

```
package mains;

import com.google.gdata.client.*;
import com.google.gdata.client.youtube.YouTubeService;
import com.google.gdata.data.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.extensions.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.media.MediaFileSource;
import com.google.gdata.data.media.mediarss.MediaCategory;
import com.google.gdata.data.media.mediarss.MediaDescription;
import com.google.gdata.data.media.mediarss.MediaKeywords;
import com.google.gdata.data.media.mediarss.MediaTitle;
import com.google.gdata.data.youtube.VideoEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.youtube.YouTubeMediaGroup;
import com.google.gdata.data.youtube.YouTubeNamespace;
import com.google.gdata.util.*;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class youtube {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Identification
        YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService("xxx",
                "yyy");

        // Upload
        VideoEntry newEntry = new VideoEntry();

        YouTubeMediaGroup mg = newEntry.getOrCreateMediaGroup();
        mg.setTitle(new MediaTitle());
        mg.getTitle().setPlainTextContent("Ma vidéo test");
        mg.addCategory(new MediaCategory(YouTubeNamespace.CATEGORY_SCHEME,
                "Cuisine"));
        mg.setKeywords(new MediaKeywords());
        // récupérer les Tags ici pour les ajouter à la Vidéo
        mg.getKeywords().addKeyword("cars");
        mg.getKeywords().addKeyword("funny");
        mg.setDescription(new MediaDescription());
        mg.getDescription().setPlainTextContent(
                "Si tu vois cette vidéo alors tous va bien");
        // public ou privé
        mg.setPrivate(true);

        MediaFileSource ms = new MediaFileSource(new File("file.mov"),
                "video/quicktime");
        newEntry.setMediaSource(ms);

        String uploadUrl = "http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads";

        VideoEntry createdEntry = service.insert(new URL(uploadUrl), newEntry);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The sample above is not V3. [Here's the right sample](https://github.com/youtube/yt-samples-java/tree/master/youtube-cmdline-uploadvideo-sample).

Comment: updated [link](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/data/UploadVideo.java)